# How can I exit completing-read with the current string instead of a completion with fido?

Tags: ido, completing-read, icomplete, fido

Consider the following code:

```lisp
(fido-mode 1)

(let ((answer (completing-read "Please enter nothing: " '("Something"))))
  (if (string= answer "")
      (message "You successfully entered nothing!")
    (message "You failed :(")))
```

How can I ensure that `answer` is the empty string (`""`)?

Both `RET` and `C-j` return `"Something"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `icomplete-fido-exit`. It's by default bound to `M-j`.

> ```
> (icomplete-fido-exit FORCE)
>
> Attempt to exit minibuffer immediately with current input.
> ```